# ETA when driving into but flying out of Canada

Tags: visas, canada, eta

I am planning to drive to Vancouver from the USA for a day and then fly from there back to Europe. I am a British Citizen. Do I need an ETA? On the [official website](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) they say that:

```
 You need an eTA to visit or transit through Canada by air.
```

In my case I will enter Canada by road, but then leave by air.

Answer (score 5):

[GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/canada/entry-requirements):

> If you’re travelling by land or sea, you won’t need an eTA when you enter Canada. However, you must travel with acceptable travel documents and identification.

You don't require an eTA to leave Canada (by air or otherwise). In fact, until and including 29 September 2016 you would be allowed to arrive by air without an eTA.